# Html audio control dissapears after page load

Tags: html, html5-audio

I have tried the following code

```
<audio controls>
<source src="pop.wav" type="audio/wav" >
    Your Browser doesn't support audio element
</audio>
```

But when i open the html file in any browser the audio control just pops up and then disappears.Why does the audio control not being displayed in the page.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the css and javascript too please. A script or style property might be causing the disappearing of the element

Comment: Second what @AndrewLyndem said. You can see from dropping your code in a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RqltRz9JRtvbXKMixRlG?p=preview) that audio controls should be visible. There has to be something else affecting it.

Comment: Could be an error with the file, location, type as well

Comment: In the console window a warning message is given l as ...                  Media resource file:///C:/...../pop.wav could not be decoded.
All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused.